# Python: how to call a method with a certain parameter being true?

Tags: python, methods

```
class Mod:
    def __init__(self, prefix='', name=None, **kws):
        self._prefix = prefix
        self.opts = kws
        self._name = name
    def _reprstring(self, long=False):
            out = self._name
            opts = []
            if len(self._prefix) > 0:
                opts.append(f"prefix='{self._prefix}'")
            if long:
                for k, v in self.opts.items():
                      opts.append(f"{k}='{v}'")
            if len(opts) > 0:
                out = f"{out}, {', '.join(opts)}"
            return f"Model({out})"
    @property
    def name(self):
         return self._reprstring(long=False)
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
         self._name = value

a=Mod(prefix='my_prefix',name='my_name',age=14,size='unknown')
a.name='olo'
print(a.name)
```

In the above code, is the only way to call `_reprstring` with `long=True` by typing `a._reprstring(long=True)`? This effectively makes the `if long` statement almost never used, then.

Is there no way of doing so while doing `print(a.name)`? --> I've tried doing `print(a.name(long=True))`, but I'm getting the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. Is this because python thinks I'm trying to call `f"Model({out})"`?

Comment: Why make `name` a property if you want to be able to pass it an argument? Keep it a regular method instead then.

Comment: implement another property: `long_name` and in that call `_reprstring(True)`. @L_S

Comment: I agree, why can't you use an other property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preserve your encapsulation of sensitive functions and data while still supporting the functionality users need by implementing another property.

```
...         @property
...         def long_name(self):
...             return self._reprstring(True)
...
>>> a=Mod(prefix='my_prefix',name='my_name',age=14,size='unknown')
>>> a.name='olo'
>>> print(a.long_name)
Model(olo, prefix='my_prefix', age='14', size='unknown')
>>>
```